# Jquery - Change screen orientation function

Tags: jquery, screen, orientation

Is it possible to create a jquery function which forces to change screen orientation?

For example I have a thumbnail of a photo. When I click on it, it gets enlarged but if the device is in portrait mode, it looks odd as it will just fill the 1/3 of screen estate. I would like to force the orientation to landscape mode when I click on the thumbnail, so the photo will appear full screen.

I tried to investigate on this but what I see orientation management is quite limited as of now. Maybe you guys have some ideas how to do this or some other alternatives to get the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned a web page forcing orientation is pretty limited but you might be able you pull off some css trickery to make it look more like you're wanting by rotating the container and resizing etc. Haven't tested below in jsFiddle but will try to little later if needed. Just a thought.

```
$('#enlargedPicture').css({
     '-moz-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
     '-webkit-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
     '-o-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
     '-ms-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
     'transform':'rotate(90deg)',
     'height':'100vh
});
```

Comment: I also started to play with CSS, not the best solution though.

Also, the thing what I want is basicly done by Youtube app on android. When you tap to full screen a video it will switch to landscape orientation. So there's must be such a clean solution.

Comment: https://codepen.io/SyWill/pen/MQVVmM actually put something on codepen so something like this wouldn't work for you? Apps on smartphones tablets etc, have a bit more access to devices api's using java,c, whatever app is written in.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I have to use this alternative CSS solution. It's interesting why there is no proper solution for forced orientation changing:/